# My published app not showing up in 2.1 market

Tags: android, marketplace

Does anyone know the step by step settings to put your app so it can show up in the 2.1 market? My app has been in the market for a few days, and a couple 2.1 users says that they cannot find it. It shows in the 2.2 though. Can someone help?

Comment: What are your manifest settings for minSdk?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

minSdkVersion="8" tells Android that your app requires sdk version 8, which is Android 2.2.  If you want to allow your app to run on lower versions of Android, you need to change the minSdk to the appropriate value.  In the case of 2.1, that would be 7.

Comment: If i upload it with minsdk 7 will 2.2 people be able to view it?  7 will let everyone 2.1 and higher download that app?

Comment: You can also specify a target and maxsdk, see http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html